# How do I store a hash which is inside an array element?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, hashmap

### The background

I got a Perl module which utilizes an array for its input/output parameters, like this:

```
Execute({inputfile => $req->{modules}.'filename', param => \@xchange});
```

Inside the module a hash is build and returned via reference

```
$param[0] = \%values;
```

This is all fine and good (I think) and `print Dumper @xchange[0];` will output my desired content as

```
$VAR1 = { '33' => 'Title1', '53' => 'Title2', '21' => 'Title3' };
```

### The goal

I would like to loop over the content and print the key/value pairs one by one, for example like this

```
%testhash = ('33' => 'Test1', '53' => 'Test2', '21' => 'Test3' );

foreach $key (keys %testhash) {
    print "LOOP: $key, value=$testhash{$key}\n";
}
```

This loop does work as intended and dumping my testhash via `print Dumper \%testhash;` outputs the same as the array element above

```
$VAR1 = { '33' => 'Test1', '53' => 'Test2', '21' => 'Test3' };
```

### The problem

The trouble now seems to be that although both structures appear to be of the same kind I cant get my head arround, how to properly access the returned hash which is stored inside @xchange[0].

I did try `%realhash = @xchange[0];` and `%realhash = \@xchange[0];`, but then `print Dumper \%realhash;` will output `$VAR1 = { 'HASH(0xa7b29c0)' => undef };` or `$VAR1 = { 'REF(0xa7833a0)' => undef };` respectively.

So I either need a way to get the content of @xchange[0] inside a clean new hash or a way to foreach loop over the hash inside the @xchange[0] element.

I guess I am getting screwed by the whole hash reference concept, but I am at a loss here and can't think of another way to google for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@xchange[0]` is a scalar value, it contains the reference to a hash. When you assign it to a hash

```
%hash = @xchange[0];
```

The reference is stringified into something like `HASH(0xa7b29c0)`, and you get the warnings

```
Scalar value @xchange[0] better written as $xchange[0] at ...
Reference found where even-sized list expected at ...
```

That is to say, you get these warnings, *unless* you have been so foolish as to not turn warnings on with `use warnings`.

The first one means what it says. The second one means that the list you assign to a hash should have an even number of elements: one value for every key. You only passed a "key" (something that Perl took as a key). The value then becomes undef, as noted in your `Data::Dumper` output:

```
$VAR1 = { 'HASH(0xa7b29c0)' => undef }
```

What you need to do is dereference the reference.

```
my $href = $xchange[0];
my %hash  = %$href;           # using a transition variable
my %hash2 = %{ $xchange[0] }  # using support curly braces
```

Comment: One is not "much", surely. I like the simplicity of `%$href`, and I feel it demonstrates what is happening well.

Answer (score 6):

`$xchange[0]` is a hash reference. Use the dereference operator `%{...}` to access it as a hash.

```
%realhash = %{$xchange[0]};
```

Comment: Is it called "dereference operator"? I've always referred to them as "support curly braces".

Comment: `%` is the dereference operator (`perldsc` calls it a "prefix derefencer"); the braces are there for precedence.

Answer (score 1):

[perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper; 
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=1;

my %testhash = ('33' => 'Test1', '53' => 'Test2', '21' => 'Test3' );

# Add hash as first element of xchange AoH
my @xchange = \%testhash;

# Derefererence 1st element of AoH as a hash
my %realhash = %{ $xchange[0] };

# Dump new hash
print Dumper(\%realhash);

__END__

$VAR1 = {
          '21' => 'Test3',
          '33' => 'Test1',
          '53' => 'Test2'
        };
```